# Elasticsearch - MissingMethodException on running distanceInKm on geo_point array

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-geo-shape

I have an elasticsearch document which has an array of geo_points. I have created the mapping as:

```
{
    "test": {
        "properties": {
            "locations": {
                "type": "geo_point"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to create a query in which I want to do some processing on the array of geo_points. I have created my query like this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "script": {
                    "script": "sDistance = doc['locations'].values[0].distanceInKm(28.51818,77.096080);"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to calculate the distance of the point (28.51818,77.096080) from the first element in the locations array.

It is giving me this error:

GroovyScriptExecutionException[MissingMethodException[No signature of method: org.elasticsearch.common.geo.GeoPoint.distanceInKm() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Double, java.lang.Double) values: [28.51818, 77.09608]]

I tried using `sDistance = doc['locations'][0].distanceInKm(28.51818,77.096080);` but it also resulted in the same error.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script should not retrieve the first geo point by itself, but simply call `distanceInKm` on the `locations` field directly, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "sDistance = doc['locations'].distanceInKm(28.51818,77.096080);"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Under the hood, the [first geo point will be retrieved](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/4c981ff4bfc250080d521af105b5e8589c9fc517/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/fielddata/ScriptDocValues.java#L205) and the distance will be [computed on it](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/4c981ff4bfc250080d521af105b5e8589c9fc517/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/fielddata/ScriptDocValues.java#L330).

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: and how to get the distance from all indexes i mean not only from 0 can you please tell me it will be really helpful for me??

Comment: Please ask another question as you're asking for a different issue.